# Delphi: windows api QOSSetFlow for request priority bandwidth usage for download/upload

Tags: delphi, winapi

i have an application that run with admin privileges. This app, make some uploads and downloads from internet. I want try to use the max of the bandwidth.

looking into winapi i found [QOSSetFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374047(v=vs.85).aspx) that (maybe) can be used for request a priority usage of the bandwidth:

> The QOSSetFlow function is called by an application to request the QOS
>   subsystem to prioritize the application's packets and change the flow
>   traffic.

I have look into Delphi Berlin but there isn't any QOSSetFlow and also search on google for "Delphi QOSSetFlow" there isn't any useful result.

It seem a unknow Windows feature into the Delphi ecosistem.

Anyone know how use QOSSetFlow in the Delphi way?

Comment: This is for the "Quality Windows Audio/Video Experience (qWAVE)", it seems to me that this is not the API method you are looking for

Comment: The documentation for [Quality Windows Audio/Video Experience (qWAVE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374110(v=vs.85).aspx) says *qWAVE provides new features focused on streaming multimedia and real-time content over variable bandwidth networks.*. Is your app *streaming multimedia and real-time content*? That's not *downloads* of files, so it's not a generic, anyone can use for anything API. Almost any API call can be made from Delphi, but you can't just randomly grab an API and plug it into anywhere for any purpose and expect it to work for you.